# Setup VPS mail server and import to Gmail

Tags: postfix, email-server, vps, dovecot

## Problem

### Setup

- There is a dedicated Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.
- There is a domain "foo.com" bought via GoDaddy.
- There is a Gmail account "some.name@gmail.com".

### Goal

The goal is to **send** a **receive** emails using **company domain** via Gmail. For example "some.name@foo.com".

Gmail allows importing and using IMAP profiles:

[image: Import IMAP profile]

I would like to do the same thing as described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEheS8gM4Xs

Except for using my own VPN instead of some 3rd party tool.

### Solution

I would assume one would need to:

- Install Postfix
- Install Dovecot
- Tweak GoDaddy DNS MX records
- Setup Postfix to communicate with Gmail (smtp.gmail.com)

Any ideas or clues how to achieve the goal set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install, configure and ensure that you have a working SMTP server.
2. Install, configure and ensure you have a working IMAP server.
3. Add the e-mail account as a [account in your gmail setup](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

There's no need to configure postfix to communicate with gmail. You simply configure gmail to fetch mail via IMAP from your mailserver.

Given your understanding of e-mail I'd be hesitant of hosting my own. It's a service where it's trivial do do non-obvious blunders that affect delivery and reputation.

Google workspace [costs 6USD/month](https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html). Your setup will be a Rube Goldberg-contraption that will probably cost comparable amounts of money, and take a lot of time to configure and maintain. It's better to simply let Google handle it.